# Generating only unique permutations

Tags: julia, permutation, combinatorics

I am using `permutations` from the [`Combinatorics`](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl) library on a list with many repeated values. My issue is that `permutations` is creating *all* permutations, leading to overflow, even though *many* of the permutations are identical.

```py
julia> collect(permutations([1, 1, 2, 2], 4))
24-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2, 1]
 [1, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2, 1]
 [1, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2, 1]
 [1, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 2]
 [2, 1, 2, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 2]
 [2, 1, 2, 1]
 [2, 2, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 1, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 2]
 [2, 1, 2, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 2]
 [2, 1, 2, 1]
 [2, 2, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Lots of identical values. What I really want are only the unique permutations, without needing to first generate all permutations:

```py
julia> unique(collect(permutations([1, 1, 2, 2], 4)))
6-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 2]
 [2, 1, 2, 1]
 [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

I could see the argument that `permutations` should always return *all* permutations, whether unique or not, but is there a way to generate *only* the unique permutations so I don't run out of memory?

Comment: `permutations` returns an iterator, so there should be no problem with memory, unless you `collect` it. Do you really need to do that? Did you try `unique(permutations(`

Comment: `unique(permutations(...))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through `unique` can be prohibitive even for vectors of relatively small size (e.g. 14 is I think already problematic). In such cases you can consider something like this:

```py
using Combinatorics, StatsBase

function trans(x, v::Dict{T, Int}, l) where T
    z = collect(1:l)
    idxs = Vector{Int}[]
    for k in x
        push!(idxs, z[k])
        deleteat!(z, k)
    end
    res = Vector{T}(undef, l)
    for (j, k) in enumerate(keys(v))
        for i in idxs[j]
            res[i] = k
        end
    end
    res
end

function myperms(x)
    v = countmap(x)
    s = Int[length(x)]
    for (k,y) in v
        l = s[end]-y
        l > 0 && push!(s, l)
    end
    iter = Iterators.product((combinations(1:s[i], vv) for (i, vv) in enumerate(values(v)))...)
    (trans(z, v, length(x)) for z in iter)
end
```

(this is a quick writeup so the code quality is not production grade - in terms of style and squeezing out maximum performance, but I hope it gives you the idea how this can be approached)

This gives you a generator of unique permutations taking into account duplicates. It is reasonably fast:

```py
julia> x = [fill(1, 7); fill(2, 7)]
14-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2

julia> @time length(collect(myperms(x)))
  0.002902 seconds (48.08 k allocations: 4.166 MiB)
3432
```

While this operation for `unique(permutations(x))` would not terminate in any reasonable size.

Comment: I think this would indeed work, but I am still running out of memory. I might just have to get clever about how I approach the problem and avoid permutations...

Comment: You do not need to `collect`. My solution can be iterated over without materializing. I just used `collect` to show you - in the small case - that it works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `multiset_permutation` in the package `Combinatorics`:

```
julia> for p in multiset_permutations([1,1,2,2],4) p|>println end
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, and use `IterTools`'s `distinct`:

```
using IterTools, Combinatorics

distinct(permutations([1, 1, 2, 2], 4))
```